# Spring security action not mapping to j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Recently I was trying to migrate sample spring security from xml to annotation.
my login form is not posting request to j_spring_security_check instead it is going to logon always. pls have a look and suggest what I am  misssing ?

posting the code and stacktrace below :-

### userlogin.jsp

```
        <form role="form" class="form" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label><input class="form-control" id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label><input class="form-control" id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <label><input type="checkbox"/> Check me out</label>
            </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

            <input type="hidden" 
                 name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

### SecurityConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123456")
            .roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/logon").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DBA') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/logon").defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/loginfailed?error=1")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout?logout").and().csrf();

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

}

### Controller.java

```
@Controller
public class UserSessionController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/logon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Locale locale, Model model) {

    return "signup";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    System.out.println("HomeController.home()");

    return "home";
}
```

}

### SpringSecurityInitializer

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
```

//do nothing
}

### logs:-

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/base/logon]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /logon
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.app.base.controller.UserSessionController.welcome(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)]
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userSessionController'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/base/logon] is: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView: name 'signup'; URL [signup]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: using spring security 3.2.5

Comment: solved it was because of missing configuration in SecurityConfig.java ..and().formLogin().loginPage("/logon").loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/loginfailed?error=1")//.usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout?logout").and().csrf();